# Migrating from Windows 8 Hyper-V to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, windows-8

Is it possible to create a VM in hyper-v on windows 8, and then migrate it to hyper-v on a windows server 2008R2 computer?

Comment: Why not try it and see. Then you'll be able to test the exact configuration you're trying to migrate. Which, you know, you'd need to do anyway regardless of what answers here said.

Comment: Its so encouraging how people often comes in here to attack the OP ,complain about the question and vote down the question! 

@DJPon3 off-course i wouldn't ask the question if it was possible at the moment to try it myself, I'm gonna have to handle the VM to someone to work with it on his Server and i wanted to make sure it will go OK

Comment: I'm sorry that you think that suggesting that you test it for yourself is somehow attacking you. I still maintain that regardless of any answer you receive here that speaks about generalities, you would still need to test your precise scenario to ensure it worked. I'm not sure what part of that you see as an "attack" or a "complaint". As for the downvote, I won't apologise for that while your question shows no hint of research - if you'd said "I've looked into this and I'm worried about *x*, can someone answer that specific point", for example, that would be quite different.

Comment: Why would you do that? ;) I use Hyper-V extensively and I an not wait to get rid of 2008 R2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on your type of virtual disk - VHDX is new to Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.  If you created your virtual machine using a vhdx disk format, it definitely won't migrate to 2008 R2.

Then it depends on the configuration of the VM (if you've exceeded the specs of a VM on 2008 R2 with the config of Win8, then you'll probably have to change the settings or possibly re-create them.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to just move the VM.  If, as the other response says, you use the VHD rather than VHDX file format, you can move the virtual disk.  It will help if you don't install the integration components in the VM, or if you uninstall them before the move.